# php elseif triggers even though it should not

Tags: php, if-statement

while trying to fetch the result of a database related function in php, i found that one of my if/elseif-statements showed a strange behavior.

```
$var = 0;

if($var)
    {echo "if triggered";}
elseif($var == "test")  
    {echo "elseif triggered";}
else
    {echo "else triggered";};

// "elseif triggered" is echoed
```

The elseif-part triggered for true even though it should not. Now i know that i can fix that by using "===" instead of only "==". I would just like to understand the logic behind that to avoid making misstakes in the future. Does it have to do with type-conversion in php or where does this behavior come from?

Best regards, Lox.

Comment: In PHP, the elseif statement is evaluated if the preceding if condition is false and its own condition is true. In your code, the condition $var == "test" is not met because $var is 0, which is not equal to the string "test". However, the elseif block is still executed because the condition $var (equivalent to $var != 0) is evaluated as false, thus the control falls into the elseif block.

Comment: This code outputs `else triggered` not `elseif triggered` - demo: https://3v4l.org/170FR. Are you running an old, unsupported version of PHP? That could be a reason for this behaviour: https://3v4l.org/170FR#v7.4.33 which has since been fixed

Comment: Thank you both. Seems like you are both are right.